# excel macros- mergine info on diff rows based on ID

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Can someone help me go through the steps of creating a macro that merges row with the same ID but with different info? This is an example:

```
ID | info1 | info2 | info3 | info4
1  | T     | F     | F     | F
1  | F     | T     | F     | F
1  | F     | F     | F     | T
2  | T     | F     | F     | F
2  | F     | F     | T     | F
```

so this would ouptut:

```
ID | info1 | info2 | info3 | info4
1  | T     | T     | F     | T
2  | T     | F     | T     | F
```

Comment: nevermind figure it out with excel macros i'll post it when I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-VBA solution, just in case.

1. Create list of unique ids.  For this
   example, id list is in Column H,
   with first entry in `H2`.
2. Enter this formula in `I2`, info1 value for ID 1:

   `=IF(SUM(IF($A$2:$A$6=$H2,IF(B$2:B$6="T",1,0),0))=0,"F","T")`
3. Adjust row numbers and columns to match your data.
4. Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter the formula as an array formula. The formula will show up in {...}.
5. Fill I2 down to cover each unique id. Fill to the right to cover each info column.